# Jsp login form Mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp, authentication

I have a login form using a JSP to check a username and password against a MySQL database. When I try to make it login it is meant to forward me to a main menu page. However, all that havens is the page goes blank and the JSP file-name is added to the end of the URL. The JSP is shown below. What am I doing wrong?

```
<%@ page language ="java" import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>

<%
String user=request.getParameter("name");
String passwrd=request.getParameter("pass");

try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/languagetest", "root", "password");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select userid,password from Users");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        String userid=rs.getString(1);
        String password=rs.getString(2);
        if(user.equals(userid) && passwrd.equals(password))
        {
            out.println("welcome");

            %>
            <jsp:forward page="Mainmenu.html"/>
        <%}
    }
}catch(Exception e1)
{}

%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are caught by an exception 
Never eat an Exception:

```
catch(Exception e1)
{}
```

---

```
catch(Exception e1)
    {e1.printStackTrace(); // also print some meaning full text for Front-End user}
```

Print stackTrace,
log the trace
show meaning full text on the JSP front page on exceptions
Most probably you are failing with the DB Connections/drivers not found

Comment: SEVERE: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure